# redux equality check for multiple values in a store

Tags: javascript, redux

currently I've faced that such a destructuring notation

```
const {selectedSpectrums, fetchedSpectraData, fetchedSpectraIndex} = useSelector(state => state.testResultsTreeReducer, isEqual);
```

works wrong and it is better to use

```
const selectedSpectrums = useSelector(state => state.testResultsTreeReducer.selectedSpectrums, isEqual);
const fetchedSpectraData = useSelector(state => state.testResultsTreeReducer.fetchedSpectraData, isEqual);
const fetchedSpectraIndex = useSelector(state => state.testResultsTreeReducer.fetchedSpectraIndex, isEqual);
```

Please help me to understand why this is wrong and how can I avoid so many similar lines and use destructuring with lodash' isEqual?

Comment: You haven't explained how the first approach "works wrong".

Comment: Well, it still triggers re-render even if all those values are same